# Akka: Stop actor after child actors are finished

Tags: java, akka, parent-child, terminate

I often find myself using a "main" actor that creates a number of child actors for sub-tasks. When the sub-tasks are finished, the main actor should also stop himself. So I watch the child actors and stop the main actor when `context.children.isEmpty`.

I often use this pattern, but as I never read about this. **I am unsure, if this is a good idea or if there are problems with failing actors...?**

I have read about [Shutdown Patterns in Akka 2](http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2), but this approach seems to be more complicated in Java than my solution?

Here is my pseudo code for a main actor with two subtasks:

```
class MainActor extends AbstractActor {

    public MainActor() {
        receive(ReceiveBuilder
                .match(SubTask1Response.class, this::handleSubTask1)
                .match(SubTask2Response.class, this::handleSubTask2)
                .match(Terminated.class, x -> checkFinished())
                .build());
    }

    @Override
    public void preStart() throws Exception {
        context().watch(context().actorOf(SubTask1Worker.props(), "subTask1"));
        context().watch(context().actorOf(SubTask2Worker.props(), "subTask2"));
    }

    private void checkFinished() {
        if(context().children().isEmpty()) {
            context().stop(self());
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

(I must use Java 8 :-(, but I am also happy to read Scala code if you can provide me another solution)

Comment: I think your approach is absolutely fine. I also read the article you linked once and i think it is more feasible for more sophisticated scenarios. In their example the Reaper seems to only watch a subset of the user guardians child actors. When you have a few distinct child actors like in your example, i would go with your approach.

Comment: Reading it once again the Reaper seems to be more a global pattern. It watches an arbitrary number of actors anywhere in the hierarchy of an actor system. But in your example you are only interested in the children of exactly one actor. 
TLDR: Go for your approach :)

Comment: You should probably (self?)close this question with an answer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `context().children().isEmpty()` seems to work as expected.

But while debugging my Akka application I found another problem with this approach: It is not deterministic when the `Terminated` message arrives in the `MainActor`: Sometimes there is the `Terminated` message *before* the `SubTask1Response` from the example!

I have changed now my code to count the running children myself and decrement the number whenever the `MainActor` receives a result response `SubTask[1,2]Response`.

=> So I wouldn't recommend my original pattern.